# How to Implement Responsive YouTube Video Framing?

Tags: embed, responsive, video-player

I am using the YouTube embed functions to place my video inside my wordpress single post page. I do not want to use oEmbed because it gives me less custimization with hiding the information bar, autoplaying, and showing related videos at the end.

The problem I am having is that, while the video looks fine on the site (you can view it here: http://diginomics.com/bitcoin-will-end-the-nation-state/), on mobile the dimensions look real wonky because it is not responsive.

Here is the embed frame code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="500" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rL66iCVZ6mE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Notice that I would like the width to be 100% of the container but not flow onto the sidebar. I would also like the height to auto adjust so that it is the correct dimension for an 1080p HD video. I have tried setting height="auto" but this does not work. Therefore, I have left the height at 500px for now.

Is there a solution for what to set the height to make it responsive for a 1080p HD video inside the wordpress container?

Comment: you may find this article on css-tricks useful: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: This sounds more CSS-Centric than WordPress-Centric

Comment: Can this please be re-opened and answered? It's a real Wordpress problem, although the solution might be pasting a single youtube URL into the wordpress editor this will not always work and we need a wordpress specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the media query for `<iframe>` responsive. Set an `id` to `<iframe>`and set `max-width` and `min-width`, and give specific size to this `<iframe>` on different device widths.

CSS:

```
<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        #res{
            width:200px; height:200px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="res" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/rL66iCVZ6mE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
```